# VB ignoring line for rules

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set off rules that classify a cell accordingly.  There are essentially 3 types of rules and the first two function correctly. The below code is used to use the italics portion of the code in the rules.  The problem is the third set of rules needs the portion in bold as well as the italics.  As of now it is not and I am not sure how to fix it.  Thank you :).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
Dim iCase As Long
Dim iLastName As Long
Dim iFirstName As Long
Dim iMedicalRecord As Long
Dim iGender As Long
Dim iPanel As Long
Dim iInheritance As Long
Dim iFuncrefGene As Long
Dim iExonicFuncrefGene As Long
Dim iPopFreqMax As Long
Dim iClinVar As Long
Dim iCommon As Long
Dim iClassification As Long

Dim vCase, vLastName, vFirstName, vMedicalRecord, vGender, vPanel, vInheritance
Dim vFuncrefGene, vExonicFuncrefGene, vPopFreqMax, vClinVar, vCommon, vClassification
Dim iRow As Long
Dim i As Long, rw As Range, rData As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'set the range
Set rData = Worksheets("annovar").Cells(4, 1).CurrentRegion

Set rw = rData.Rows(1)
'search row and define criteria
With Application.WorksheetFunction
iCase = .Match("Case", rData.Rows(1))
iLastName = .Match("Last Name", rData.Rows(1), 0)
iFirstName = .Match("First Name", rData.Rows(1), 0)
iMedicalRecord = .Match("Medical Record", rData.Rows(1), 0)
iGender = .Match("Gender", rData.Rows(1), 0)
iPanel = .Match("Panel", rData.Rows(1), 0)
iInheritance = .Match("Inheritance", rData.Rows(4), 0)
iPopFreqMax = .Match("PopFreqMax", rData.Rows(4), 0)
iClinVar = .Match("ClinVar", rData.Rows(4), 0)
iCommon = .Match("Common", rData.Rows(4), 0)
iFuncrefGene = .Match("Func.refGene", rData.Rows(4), 0)
iExonicFuncrefGene = .Match("ExonicFunc.refGene", rData.Rows(4), 0)
iClassification = .Match("Classification", rData.Rows(4), 0)
End With

' Classifications
For iRow = 2 To rData.Rows.Count ‘Start at line #2 to ignore the header row

Set rw = rData.Rows(iRow)

vCase = rw(iCase).Value
vLastName = rw(iLastName).Value
vFirstName = rw(iFirstName).Value
vMedicalRecord = rw(iMedicalRecord).Value
vGender = rw(iGender).Value
vPanel = rw(iPanel).Value
vInheritance = rw(iInheritance).Value
vPopFreqMax = rw(iPopFreqMax).Value
vClinVar = rw(iClinVar).Value
vCommon = rw(iCommon).Value
vFuncrefGene = rw(iFuncrefGene).Value
vExonicFuncrefGene = rw(iExonicFuncrefGene).Value
vClassification = “”

‘pathogenic
Select Case vClinVar
    Case “pathogenic”
        vClassification = “pathogenic”
    Case “non-pathogenic”
        vClassification = “benign”
    Case “unknown”
        vClassification = “VUS”
    Case “untested”
        vClassification = “not provided”
End Select

If vInheritance = “XL” Or “unknown” Or “sporadic, AD” or “de novo, AD”  Then vClassification = “unknown”

If vClassification = “” And vClinVar = “” Then   

    If vInheritance = "AD" Then

                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01) Or _
                            (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon) = "") Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.01) Or _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value = "synonymous SNV" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01) Or _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon) = "") Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"


                              ' questionable
                        If .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous SNV" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01 And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                        End If

    If vInheritance = "AR" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.1) Or _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon) = "") Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.1) Or _
                            (.Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.1 And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                        End If


   If vInheritance = "AD, AR" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD, AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.1) Or _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon) = "") Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD, AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.1) Or _
                            (.Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD, AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.1 And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "AD, AR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                    End If

   If vInheritance = "XLD" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01) Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLD" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.01) Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                             .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLD" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") Or _
                           .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01) Or _
                           .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                              .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLD" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") Or _
                           .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                              .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                    End If

   If vInheritance = "XLR for male" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                          (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01) Or _
                           .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                              .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.01) Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01 And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                    End If

If vInheritance = "XLR for female" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.02) Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.02) Or _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.02) And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                    End If

If vInheritance = "XLD, XLR" And vGender = "Male" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                          (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01) Or _
                           .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                           .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                              .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.01) Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.01 And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Male") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                                .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                    End If

If vInheritance = "XLD, XLR" And vGender = "Female" Then
                              ' likely pathogenic
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.02) Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-pathogenic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic"
                              ' likely benign
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value >= 0.02) Or _
                           (.Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Or _
                            .Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "probable-non-pathogenic") Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely benign"
                              ' questionable
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iFuncrefGene).Value = "exonic" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iExonicFuncrefGene).Value <> "synonymous" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <> "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value <= 0.02) And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "Common" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "???"
                              ' unknown
                        If (.Cells(iRow, iClinVar).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iInheritance).Value = "XLR" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iGender).Value = "Female") And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iPopFreqMax).Value = "" And _
                            .Cells(iRow, iCommon).Value = "" Then _
                               .Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "unknown"
                    End If
‘ Populate classification value
rw(iClassification).Value = vClassification

Next iRow
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  What is the third set of rules?  Right now your code will raise a run-time error if any of those terms are not found in the expected row - is that what you want?

Comment: The complete code is now posted.  I will try to explain (hopefully better), the categories of rules are AD, AR, AD and AR, XLD, XLR for males, XLR for females, and XL.  The first 3 work correctly.... it is the X... rule that is not working. I don't know why exactly but suspect that in the Dim line the iGender is used in the X... rule and I think it is being ignored and I am not sure how to include it while leaving the other rules alone (still working).  Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge amount of code in your question, and it can be substantially reduced by not testing the same things over and over.

I would start by using actual variables for the values, instead of going to the sheet every time: just doing that alone would reduce the volume of your code significantly.

You also only need to loop over the rows once - just run each test on every row until you get a value for Classification.  When you repeat code it's harder to follow, and the chance of bugs goes up significantly after any edit.

Then factor out the common tests - eg the first four can go in a Select Case and once done don't need to be repeated for every value of Inheritance.

Here's a start (just a skeleton, since there's too much for me to factor it all down to a core set)

```
Option Explicit '<<<< always use this at the tp of your modules

Sub Tester()
Dim iCase As Long
Dim iLastName As Long
Dim iFirstName As Long
Dim iMedicalRecord As Long
Dim iGender As Long
Dim iPanel As Long
Dim iInheritance As Long
Dim iFuncrefGene As Long
Dim iExonicFuncrefGene As Long
Dim iPopFreqMax As Long
Dim iClinVar As Long
Dim iCommon As Long
Dim iClassification As Long

Dim vCase, vLastName, vFirstName, vMedicalRecord, vGender, vPanel, vInheritance
Dim vFuncrefGene, vExonicFuncrefGene, vPopFreqMax, vClinVar, vCommon, vClassification
Dim iRow As Long
Dim i As Long, rw As Range, rData As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'set the range
Set rData = Worksheets("annovar").Cells(4, 1).CurrentRegion

Set rw = rData.Rows(1)
'search row and define criteria
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    iCase = .Match("Case", rData.Rows(1))
    iLastName = .Match("Last Name", rData.Rows(1), 0)
    iFirstName = .Match("First Name", rData.Rows(1), 0)
    iMedicalRecord = .Match("Medical Record", rData.Rows(1), 0)
    iGender = .Match("Gender", rData.Rows(1), 0)
    iPanel = .Match("Panel", rData.Rows(1), 0)
    iInheritance = .Match("Inheritance", rData.Rows(4), 0)
    iPopFreqMax = .Match("PopFreqMax", rData.Rows(4), 0)
    iClinVar = .Match("ClinVar", rData.Rows(4), 0)
    iCommon = .Match("Common", rData.Rows(4), 0)
    iFuncrefGene = .Match("Func.refGene", rData.Rows(4), 0)
    iExonicFuncrefGene = .Match("ExonicFunc.refGene", rData.Rows(4), 0)
    iClassification = .Match("Classification", rData.Rows(4), 0)
End With

' AD
 For iRow = 2 To rData.Rows.Count 'Start at line #2 to ignore the header row

    Set rw = rData.Rows(iRow)

    vCase = rw(iCase).Value
    vLastName = rw(iLastName).Value
    vFirstName = rw(iFirstName).Value
    vMedicalRecord = rw(iMedicalRecord).Value
    vGender = rw(iGender).Value
    vPanel = rw(iPanel).Value
    vInheritance = rw(iInheritance).Value
    vPopFreqMax = rw(iPopFreqMax).Value
    vClinVar = rw(iClinVar).Value
    vCommon = rw(iCommon).Value
    vFuncrefGene = rw(iFuncrefGene).Value
    vExonicFuncrefGene = rw(iExonicFuncrefGene).Value
    vClassification = ""

    'pathogenic
    Select Case vClinVar
        Case "pathogenic"
            vClassification = "pathogenic"
        Case "non-pathogenic"
            vClassification = "benign"
        Case "unknown"
            vClassification = "VUS"
        Case "untested"
            vClassification = "not provided"
    End Select

    If vInheritance = "XL" Then vClassification = "unknown"

    If vClassification = "" And vClinVar = "" Then

        If vInheritance = "AD" Then
            'do AD tests

        End If

        If vInheritance = "AR" Then
            'do AR tests

        End If

        'etc etc

    End If

    'finally, populate the classification value (if any was allocated)
    rw(iClassification).Value = vClassification

  Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I modified the VB trying to follow your example, are you able to look it over (I am new to VB).  Thank you for all your help :).

Comment: I will email you a copy of the workbook and yes I did use word... i don't know why I always seem to though.  Thanks.